# Insert record into Data Extension from a Journey

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, create-records, new

I would like to keept track of my sent out emails by writing away the data such as "Sent Date", "Theme", "Reason of contacting" into a "Contact History" Data Extension. This, as we only have the SF Marketing Cloud.

I am looking for the best way to write away this data into this Data Extension.

I have set up a Journey in the Journey Builder, where I can select the customers who I want to contact and send the email from.

Now the question comes: where and how do I write away the above mentioned information (Sent Date, Theme, Reason of contacting) into a new record on the Data Extension "Contact History". This Data Extension, as well as the Data Extension where all the original data resides, have an SubscriberKey and Email-Address Attribute (to 'link' the 2 tables).

I have tried using the "Update Contact"-tool however and this allows me to set some of the attributes, but only with values I set fix in the Journey. However, it does not allow me to set the Email-Address with the value of the selected record's Email-Address.

Thank you for your aid!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do is create a Data Extension to store the data, and then use UPSERTDE AMPscript within your email to add records to the DE as the email is sending.

[UPSERT DE AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertde.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Insert Contact" function on Journey Builder up to today.

There are two options:

1. Develop [custom activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm), implement insert into DE via SOAP or REST API in your webservice.
2. In the data extension for your entry source, before activating the journey, you can modify the data extension by adding extra columns. In Journey, use "Update contact" function to update those extra columns with the output from your journey data. Then setup automation to query against entry source data extension to extract the values from those extra columns and populate the records into your "Contact History" DE